# Unix Socket returns ECONNRESET, and server doesn't even get accept to stop blocking

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, unix

So, I'm playing with Unix sockets, and they were working well for a while. Now when I connect, I get a `ECONNRESET` & the server's accept doesn't even stop blocking.
Accept code:

```
socklen_t slt = sizeof(sun);
int i = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sun, &slt);
```

Read code:

```
jbyte* ra = malloc(size);
memset(ra, 0, size);
int i = read(sockfd, ra, size);
```

There's a lot more, but this is all through JNI. I've verified through debugging that accept is hanging, the sockets are listening, etc. I've also verified they never stop blocking. Furthermore, I do a write, then when I try to read, I get a `ECONNRESET`. My server is running as an unprivileged user, while my client is running as root.

Socket file(s, there are two cases of this), from `ls -la`:

```
srwxr-xr-x  1 ap_6840 ap_6840      0 May 21 22:52 .api.sock
srwxr-xr-x  1 ap_6840 ap_6840      0 May 21 22:52 .http.sock
```

So, they are created, listening, etc. If you want more code, tell me what.

EDIT:

Connect code:

```
struct sockaddr_un sun;
sun.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strncpy(sun.sun_path, npath, 108);
int i = connect((int)sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sun, sizeof(sun));
```

with npath being my file.
Entire C file: https://github.com/JavaProphet/Avuna-HTTPD/blob/master/csrc/org_avuna_httpd_util_CLib.c

Java code tying it together: https://github.com/JavaProphet/Avuna-HTTPD/tree/master/src/org/avuna/httpd/util/unixsocket

Comment: I've also verified it's connecting to the right file.

Comment: You need to provide more code than this. I would want to see the connect code and the code that writes and reads. The most obvious conclusion at the moment is that you're connecting to the wrong thing.

Comment: @EJP I added more code to the post, and links to all of the code.

Comment: No links. Code that forms part of a question must be included in the question.

Comment: Use `lsof -p <pid-of-server>` to check that your server doesn't leak file/socket descriptors. Lack of descriptors on the server would cause the effect too.

Comment: @Dummy00001 Nope, not the issue. I also did some permission checking, including chown/chmod the file, same error. As far as I can tell, the kernel is just blocking the connection?

Comment: Kernel has no reason to block anything. Use `strace` to actually verify that the client/server code does what you think it does.

Comment: "*I do a write, then when I try to read*" please where is the code doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my console was buried under 2 parent processes, so I never looked at it. I was calling free on stack memory in my accept method.